How can I enter to a virtual environment previously created to install new libraries in it?
I’m having problems in Thonny with the picamera module. I can see it when I enter into manage packages. I also tried to install picamera2 which is already installed but not in the virtual environment that I need it in. How can I install picamera2 for the virtual environment that I’m using or can I create a new virtual environment with the exact same files (opencv, a distance sensor and aruco markers) and add the correct picamera file?
I tried installing it from the “manage packages” in Thonny but it gives me an error saying that I need “libcap”

Sorry, no knowledge about Thonny, used only VSCode and PyCharm.
You should be able to configure Thonny source for running python (like from venv/Scripts/python).
And python package maybe will be easier with pip.
> source venv/Scripts/activate   
> pip install <your package>   
> pip list/freeze # to see the local packages   

